# Unable to upload file using presigned POST S3 URL from Wix

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, velo

I am trying to upload a file to AWS S3 (using a presigned POST URL with no conditions) from Wix platform. The code I use is below. I get successful response from the JS but I see only 15B in AWS S3 and the content should be an image but is actually text. I am starting to feel like I have to send binary data as I upload the file but not sure. This is why I wanted to check if the code is valid. Can you help me with this?

```
async function uploadFile(file) {
    let presignedData = await fetchPresignedData()
    console.log(presignedData)
    let formData = new FormData();
    
    Object.entries(presignedData.fields).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        formData.append(key, value);
    });
    formData.append('file', file); // file is a File object that has attributes name, size, valid and validation_message

    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    });

    // Use fetch to perform the file upload
    await fetch(presignedData.url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
    })
};
```

Tested adding Content-Type as header and as part of FormData but I either get Bad request or Forbidden.
Upload works using Python locally.

Comment: What is the uploaded text? Does it give you any clue as to what is happening?

Comment: Yes, the text is `[object Object]` which is the same thing that I would get if I do console.log(file).

Comment: I would guess that the `file` argument passed into `uploadFile()` is neither a Blob nor a File, so the value is converted to a string, represented as "[object Object]". I would check the type of the `file` argument.

Comment: I am starting to feel that File in Velo is not the same as File in traditional Javascript.
https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/uploadbutton/value
This is the structure I have but unsure how to transfer to an actual JS File type or Blob to be able to upload.

Comment: Given that Velo seems to provide Wix-specific file uploader features, you might have to create a custom uploader that targets S3. A related post that might help [here](https://forum.wixstudio.com/t/when-using-a-wix-upload-button-i-need-the-full-path-name-to-the-uploaded-file-in-order-to-transfer-it-to-aws-s3-can-you-help-me/21986/8).